# What is phi in Deep Q-learning algorithm

Tags: java, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, q-learning

I'm trying to make a learning football game from scratch with Java and I'm  trying to implement the reinforcement learning with Google DeepMind's Deep Q-learning algorithm (without convolutional network though). I've already built neural network and Q-learning and now I'm trying to sum them up together but there are somethings I don't understand in this code.

1. Aren't Q-values usually initialized with zeros instead of random values? Or does this mean the weights of the neural network (line 2)
2. What is meant by

> preprocessed sequenced *Φ1 = Φ(s1)* (line 4)

I just couldn't figure out what does Φ stand for in this algorithm.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It refers to the weights of the neural network
2. Φ(s) refers to the preprocessing map/step, Φ is a shorthand for Φ(s1)
   Each frame is 210x160 pixels x 128 colors. Some preprocessing was used in the paper. They remove flickering, use only luminance, rescale and stack.
   Have a look at the 'Methods' section in the 2015 paper.

Comment: Nice, thank you! I hadn't even found that 2015 paper before, I'm gonna read this through now.